# LOBYTE(nValue) and LOBYTE(LOWORD(nValue)) Difference?

Tags: c++

What is the difference between the 2 statements?
Here assume nValue is an integer of 4 bytes.
My belief is that both are the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say they both produce exactly the same result. BYTE and WORD are both unsigned (assuming standard Windows definitions). So if nValue is signed or unsigned, it shouldn't make any difference. In all cases, you should end up with the lowest 8 bits of nValue.

Answer (score 2):

They're exactly equivalent to each other.

Answer (score 1):

Both are exactly same if you mean Microsoft Win32's Macros:

```
//from Windef.h
#define LOWORD(l)           ((WORD)(((DWORD_PTR)(l)) & 0xffff))
#define LOBYTE(w)           ((BYTE)(((DWORD_PTR)(w)) & 0xff))
```

However, `LOBYTE(nValue)` is better syntactically (or maybe, performance-wise as well), because it gives you the result at once.

Comment: Any reasonable compiler would optimize the code such that I would expect performance to also be identical.